# async in script doesn't act like multithreading but similar to defer

Tags: javascript, html

I theoretically know the differences between **`async`** and **`defer`** used in `<script>` tag.

**`async`**: **The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing).**

**`defer`**: **The script is executed when the page has finished parsing.**

But can't understand the mechanism they follow.

I have the following 2 files-`1.js` and `1.html`.

### 1.js

```
alert('Running external JS');
```

### 1.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="1.js" async></script>
        <script>
            for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                alert('HTML code1');
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                alert('HTML code2');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The html file executes s.t. all the `alert` statements execute first and then at last the script `1.js` executes i.e. it acts similarly as when I use `defer` in place of `async` in the `<script>`-tag.

As per my expectation as the external script is much smaller than the code in the HTML itself ***it should have been triggered anywhere in between the `alert` statements in the HTML document*** as I am using `async` but acting similar to the effect of using `defer`.

Please explain what happened here also please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that _async_ and _defer_ only apply to `<script>`s in the `<head>`.

Comment: You should also include `<!DOCTYPE html>` to ensure the browser is in standards mode.

Comment: what does **standards mode** signify? What are the issues effected by **standards mode**???

Comment: Standards mode means the browser is doing it's best to follow the standards of the W3C and IETF, as opposed to quirks mode, where browsers behave as they like; usually to maintain backwards-compatibility with previous versions of the same browser. Specifying a doctype and writing valid html mean the browser will default to standards mode. If it encounters something invalid, it switches to quirks mode and starts guessing what you want.

Comment: @PaulS.: you sure about that?  I don't usually place scripts in the body, but I'm not sure whether this is the case.

Comment: That being said, I still see what OP is talking about -- (open console) http://jsbin.com/IQOGoJo/1

Comment: `async` means you don't want to maintain execution order of `<script>` especially those inline scripts between script tag will be executed immediately. Have you use the browser console to see the page load timeline?

Comment: Not sure if alert messages are the best way to test this – as they interrupt everything that’s going on quite heavily by blocking the UI until they are clicked away. I’d rather go for console.log instead.

Comment: And a for loop blocks everything else until it is finished, so that’s maybe not the best indicator as well. And however small your external script is, it still means an HTTP request with all its overhead. Executing ten alert statements (which not necessarily means _showing_ the actual message windows, but maybe just putting them on an internal stack) might quite well be faster than fetching, parsing and executing the external script and therefor be done with earlier.

Comment: @CBroe that's why I have used 2 for loops and was expecting the script to be executed in the transition between them.